# How to know which number on dual-SIM phone was called?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, calls, dual-sim

I have a phone with dual SIM cards. When somebody calls me, I can see the calling number and used network.

How can I know which of my SIM cards received the call?

Comment: Can you clarify? You want to know the witch number (your number) the person called?

Comment: yes, exactly, which my number

Comment: what phone model you have?

Comment: @fcm, blu win hd lte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took long time for me to find out how I can see to which sim somebody calling.

Call is displaying in different color.

For example if call to sim 1, I see the following:

[image]

and for sim 2:

[image]

I cropped images, to show only scrennshot buttom.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Truecaller](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/truecaller/9wzdncrfj3ml). Its a free app and can be downloaded from the store. When somebody is calling you and your data or wifi in ON, it will show you the name of the person(If that number is in its database with the person name).

Comment: I need no name, who is calling, but to which my number (sim) is calling.

Comment: but anyway, I'll try it